# Optimization about Singleton

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity with c#.
I have two objects and one needs to call a function from the other which is a Singleton. For this I have two solutions. But what's the best thing to do :
 - Call for :
`MyScript.Instance.MyFunc();`
 - Store my Singleton object in my calling object and call it like this :
`myScript.MyFunc();`

What is the best thing to do in term of performance and optimizations.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/60100/optimization-question-about-singleton . Please choose one site or the other for asking a question. In this case, you should remove the one on GD.SE.

Comment: The correct answer is "whatever expresses the concept you are representing best". The point at which you need to optimise this, is the point where you do something *completely* different.

Answer (score 0):

A second variant will be better, because Instance property check current instance for null value every time.

Answer (score 0):

> MyScript.MyFunc();

The class should handle the instance internally, and it should be private.  You don't need the "Instance" clutter everywhere, and nobody else needs to know about it.